# I am getting single image for the entire video which i render in blender

Tags: rendering, edit-mode, video

I am using blender software to edit my videos. When i try render animation for the final output. the video contains only single frame for entire video.

Software: blender.

OS: Ubunutu.

[image]

Rendered video:

[image]

Comment: You need to select _Render Animation_ from the Render Menu (CTRL-F12)

Comment: yes, I did that.

Comment: i have added a video into sequencer and when i try to render animation only single frame is rendering for the entrie duration of the video.

Comment: those values are auto populated, but I tried with 60,1 still same result. Could you please suggest me way to post the video here.

Comment: My entire project for this editing: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12CuI9cEDkfhXhE7u9ToYtmNIKSjlw1If?usp=sharing

Comment: I tried downloading your blend file and plugged in a different video and sound into the strip you had setup and it rendered fine. So I think @vklidu might be right about your source video.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is your source video.
I don't have a clue what is that, I'm not a codec master, but there is some mismatch with FPS. Even it is marked as 59.49 (in blender and other players), you can see blender is trying to recalculate FPS to some weird values.

When I resave your source video in QuickTime to MOV it is loaded into blender with 120 fps and is rendered fine.
(but FPS is weird anyway in QT or VLC it still shows 59,4something).

If you place source video again into same blend file strip is endless (?!)

---

Even resave works for me, it is not clear what is going on there ... I wrote it as an answer just because comments became too long.